# Format value in model class in ASP.NET Core using EF code-first

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-code-first

I have a model like this:

```
public class InventoryRequest
{
        private static int _nextSequenceNumber = 1;

        [Key]
        [Required]
        public int InventoryRequestId { get; set; }
        public string? RequestNumber { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
        public DateTime? RequestDate { get; set; }
        public string RequestNotes { get; set; }

        public InventoryRequest()
        {
            const string fixedString = "31751/PL.711/";
            var month = DateTime.Today.Month;
            var year = DateTime.Today.Year;

            if (InventoryRequestId == 0) // Only generate a new RequestNumber for new objects
            {
                RequestNumber = $"B-{_nextSequenceNumber:D3}/{fixedString}{month}/{year}";
                _nextSequenceNumber++;
            }
        }
}
```

If you see that the request number will be filled automatically. But, I want to make sure that there's no duplicate on the table also every time create a new record, it should be always generate new number from the latest. For example, if the latest number is 5, then the new number would be 6. If there's no record at all, it would be 1.

Please advice.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment:

Lots of issues with your implementation.  Static field will reset when process restarts, for example, and if the code runs in multiple processes, they will each have their own, duplicated values.  You also have a multi threading issue where multiple threads can enter what should be a mutex block (the if block) and this use the same sequence number multiple times before it’s incremented.  Yet another issue is that when you load entities from the DB, inventory request ID will always be the default value of 0 in the constructor, needlessly incrementing the sequence number.  EF constructs the object (which runs the constructor), then assigns property values.

Comment: Then what should I do brother?

Comment: Outside the scope of SO question/answer, unfortunately.  Research concurrency, race conditions, mutex, etc.  easiest option would probably be to move the request number generation to your data store, which would be provider specific.